# Mass upload .csv to wordpress or woocommerce as products

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to mass upload wordpress pages. I have a .csv that needs to go into wordpress as pages. Could I map the wp_content and upload the csv; would that show up on wordpress?

I was thinking of doing it with csv table with phpmyadmin. Has anyone tried? Could someone show me if that's possible or not possible?

[image]

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: i looked around wordpress and i installed a csv importer for woocommerce; which i know needs to be mapped out to the .csv. my questions is has anyone done it and work it worked?

Comment: most definetly doable. Look at woocomerce (or wordpress) at the point where what you want to save is saved, and folow their lead. Doing everything by hand by means of mysql queries is a lot harder as wordpress is built upon meta tables, which means things will not be as apparent as normal tables with foreign keys and clearer entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it totally depends upon what data your product have.  if it only have `title` and `content` then phpmyadmin will be the best way.

If it have some additional data such as `product_thumbnail` , `price`, `variation` then i will suggest you to make a custom php script which will pull up the data from csv file and put that in wordpress / woocommerce.

By this way you can reduce your efforts by using wordpress native functions such as wp_insert_post(), update_meta_field() etc

Comment: I figured it out-- I guess instead of reinventing the wheel; I went ahead and used a csv importer from the wordpress community.